# How to cast a char* to jbyteArray in JNI whitout malloc a new memory area

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a code mixed Java and C, I need pass a byte[] of Java code to C code to complete some calculate.I convert byte[] to char* by using below code in JNI(env is JNIEnv * of C):

```
jboolean is_copy = JNI_TRUE;
char *native_byte_array = (char *) (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, byte_array, &is_copy);
```

I finished calculate with type char* and the return value has type char* too,I want to return a value with jbyteArray so I can use it in type byte[] in Java.I have try the below code in JNI(env is JNIEnv * of C):

```
jbyteArray java_buffer = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, buffer_size);

(*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, java_buffer, 0, buffer_size, (const jbyte *) native_buffer);
```

It seems like that NewByteArray will create a new byte[] instance and SetByteArrayRegion will copy data into the new created byte[].
However,it's not efficient if I have a big return value that need to be cast to byte[].
So,is there a way that can create a jbyteArray instance without malloc new memory and make it point to the char* area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NewDirectByteBuffer`. (I know, it's not the same as a byte[], but it comes quite near)
To return:

```
//Do something...
char* result=...;
return (*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer(env, result, buffer_size);
```

To pass:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Foo_bar(JNIEnv* env,jclass cls, jobject buffer){
  char* bufferPassedFromJava=(*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,buffer);//May return NULL
}
```

These DirectByteBuffers are, simplified just a small wrapper around a long (The address), so you can use them without copying arrays around

Comment: Thanks.Use GetDirectBufferAddress and NewDirectByteBuffer method help me cast data between byte[] in Java and char* in JNI.However, the return value of NewDirectByteBuffer is a DirectByteBuffer instance which hasArray() return false and array() method is unsupported.If I want to get the origin byte[] in the DirectByteBuffer instance, I need use ByteBuffer.get(int index) to loop through  the origin byte[] in the DirectByteBuffer instance and make a copy to a new byte[].This is almost do the same thing like use NewByteArray and SetByteArrayRegion.

Comment: You could write your own implementation of `DirectByteBuffer`, that implements `ByteBuffer`, with all methods you need. This class has one attribute long, from there, the `byte[]` is lazily copied to a bytearray, because you will ALWAYS have to copy the array.

Comment: You are right, I always have to copy the array.I will choose a suitable method.

Comment: *around a long (The address)* A `long` value is not sufficient to hold an address.  Addresses on 64-bit Windows are 64 bits, but a `long` on 64-bit Windows is only 32 bits.

Comment: I mean a Java long (64 bits). @AndrewHenle